# Will we be able to forget our past once we are in paradise?

Tags: jannah

My question is in regards to life in paradise. I have read that the people of paradise will be able to recall their earthly life, including the trials they faced.

I would like to know if we will be able to permanently forget our past if we do so wish? As in, is it possible that we will never have to think about our earthly life at all if we pray and wish to never think about it, so that we may completely forget it?

Comment: In Jinnah, a general rule if you can imagine it you can get it. Don't let anyone limit the possibilities for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
                                  بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

In regards to forgetting our past life memories when we’ll be reached in paradise (God willing), almost, I can remember a same issue as a related matter with your inquiry, that it was said that people will forget their past practices and lives when they’ll go to the paradise. (Of course it seems to be related to negative practices of the life, not good positives practices). Although it could be possible to remember our nice previous matters and events or whatever we are interested in.

Meanwhile, on the other hand, it could be considered as a rational issue that people will be free from bad memories of the world in order to be happy in the paradise and enjoying it. Otherwise it would be considered as a painful paradise!  And God knows best

Answer (score 0):

In Jannah, it possible to forget all our memories if we wish, but if those memories are giving us "a thanking attitude towards ALLAH" then people will surely remember their those days & they will not have any problem for remembering those days.

For example, verse of QURAN says,

> BISMILLAHI RRAHMANI RRAHEEM
>
> So Allah conferred favor upon us and protected us from the punishment
>   of the Scorching Fire. [52:27]
>
> Indeed, we used to supplicate Him before. Indeed, it is He who is the
>   Beneficent, the Merciful." [52:28]
>
> Sadaqallahul azeem

And even some person who commit sin in this world and done Tawba (repent), and ALLAH grant him JANNAH after accepting his Tawba, then also in Jannah that person will remember this favor of ALLAH on him.

And ALLAH knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Once you enter the paradise your wishes will be answered and one of you wishes may be to forget your bad deeds.
Paradise is not a place of torment.

On the day of Judgement however we will remember each and everything that we have done - good or bad.

Answer (score -1):

No, you will not forget your past. The Qur'an says in 2:25:

"And give good tidings to those who believe and do righteous deeds that they will have gardens [in Paradise] beneath which rivers flow. Whenever they are provided with a provision of fruit therefrom, they will say, "This is what we were provided with before." And it is given to them in likeness. And they will have therein purified spouses, and they will abide therein eternally."

This ayah implies that we will remember what life was like on earth, and be able to compare it to paradise.